FFMPEG cannot record Multicast with Transport Stream containing encrypted programs
I have a problem.
I have a multicast source that contains a Transport Stream with programs encrypted by a Nagra CAS system. I need to record this transport stream transparently without the need to decode the services, but FFMPEG seems to necessarily decode in order to record, and if it doesn't find a codec for the recording, it won't proceed.
Here’s what I have done so far:
ffmpeg -re -i udp://235.0.0.1:5000 -c copy -f mpegts -t 10 "C:\Videos\TS01.ts"

And here's the output:
ffmpeg version 2024-07-15-git-350146a1ea-full_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers   built with gcc 13.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)   configuration: --enable-gpl
--enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-libsnappy --enable-zlib --enable-librist --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-sdl2 --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libquirc --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libxevd --enable-libzvbi --enable-libqrencode --enable-librav1e --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libvvenc --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxeve --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libjxl --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-frei0r --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-liblensfun --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-dxva2 --enable-d3d11va --enable-d3d12va --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libvpl --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-vaapi --enable-libshaderc --enable-vulkan --enable-libplacebo --enable-opencl --enable-libcdio --enable-libgme --enable-libmodplug --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libshine --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libilbc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-ladspa --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libmysofa --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-chromaprint   libavutil      59. 28.100 / 59. 28.100   libavcodec     61. 10.100 / 61. 10.100   libavformat    61.  5.101 / 61.  5.101   libavdevice    61.  2.100 / 61.  2.100   libavfilter    10.  2.102 / 10.  2.102   libswscale      8.  2.100 / 
8.  2.100   libswresample   5.  2.100 /  5.  2.100   libpostproc    58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100 [mpegts @ 000001c133a04c00] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), none): unspecified size Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (10000000) and 'probesize' (10000000) options Input
#0, mpegts, from 'udp://235.0.0.1:5000':   Duration: N/A, start: 57844.232622, bitrate: 4480 kb/s   Program 46   Stream #0:7[0x1afa]: Unknown: none ([11][0][0][0] / 0x000B)   Program 807
    Metadata:
      service_name    : TVN HD
      service_provider:   Stream #0:30[0xd1c](spa): Audio: mp3 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 0 channels, 128 kb/s   Stream #0:31[0x8c0]: Video: h264 ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), none, 128 kb/s, 90k tbn   [AVFormatContext @ 000001c134528080] Requested output format 'mpegtsraw' is not known. [out#0 @ 000001c1344dbac0] Error initializing the muxer for C:\Videos\TS01.ts: Invalid argument Error opening output file C:\Videos\TS01.ts. Error opening output files: Invalid argument

Can anyone help me by indicating how I can make a clean recording of a transport stream with encrypted services using ffmpeg or some other command line software?
